# Arithmetic series and sequences

Tags: arithmetic

I can’t seem to find term 1. I already know the answer, but they want me to show the work. I’ve been trying for hours. It always comes out the wrong answer.
d= 6 Sn= -256 N = 32
I need to find the first term.
The right answer is -101

Comment: What formula do you know for $S_n$?

Comment: Sn = n/2(2t1+(n-l)d

Comment: So you have $-256 = \frac{32}2(2T_1 + (32-1)(6))$. Can't you do the algebra?

Comment: Yes but I keep getting 202? When the answer is -101

Comment: I solve my equation and get the right answer ($-101$). I think it's time you edited your question with your exact working.

Comment: I’m so confused

Comment: Show your working, the actual algebra. You *have* the right formula. And disregard that wrong answer below.

Comment: The $(32-1)(6)$ is a separate term. You need to work this out first as $(31)(6) = 186$. Then add $2T_1$ to give $2T_1 + 186$. Don't forget the whole thing is multiplied by $\frac {32}2$ which is $16$.

Comment: -256 = 16 + 2t1 + 186

Comment: You expanded wrongly. You should have $-256 = 16(2T_1 + 186)$. Do you know how to "open the brackets" (distribute)? The $16$ needs to multiply by each term, then the products are added. Remember $A(B+C) = AB + AC$.

Comment: Also you might find it easier to divide both sides by $16$ to get $-16 = 2T_1 + 186$. This avoids having to open the brackets by distribution. But I'd rather you do it the original way, since it's basic algebra and you should really be comfortable with it by now.

Comment: So 186 multiplied 16, and -256 is also multiplied by 16? Sorry. I get all of my information online. My school never gave me any information or a textbook. They just handed me a stack of work.

Comment: I cannot comment on why your school system seems to have failed you in basic algebra so badly. There are some online resources that can teach you how to do basic things like distribution. Like this: https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/distributive-property-algebra.html But you may have deficits elsewhere that need to be addressed, and I'm afraid this is not the place to take you through the basics patiently. Please find a good textbook or online resource or, best of all, a personal tutor.

Comment: I have given you a complete answer this time. But please follow my advice. You really need to work on your algebra. You simply cannot progress without a firm foundation in basic algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $S_n= \frac n2(2T_1 +(n-1)d)$, we have:

$-256 = \frac{32}2(2T_1 + (32-1)(6))$

$-256 = 16(2T_1 + 31(6))$

$-256 = 16(2T_1 + 186)$

And here you can proceed either by distribution:

$-256 = 16(2T_1) + 16(186)$

$-256 = 32T_1 + 2976$

$32T_1 = -256 - 2976$

$32T_1 = - 3232$

$T_1 = - 101$

*Or* you can proceed by division from this step:

$-256 = 16(2T_1 + 186)$

$-\frac{256}{16} = 2T_1 + 186$

$-16 = 2T_1 +186$

$2T_1 = - 202$

$T_1 = - 101$

Either way, the answer is the same ($-101$).

As I suggested in the comments, please really work on your algebra. It is absolutely essential for every area of mathematics. Without that foundation you'll find progressing very difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @Baileysylvester If my answer (and I guess all my comments too) helped you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: How do I do that? Ha

Comment: @Baileysylvester I think if you click under the downvote button on my answer (not on the downvote button lol), there should be a tick symbol. If it turns green, it means you've accepted my answer. :)